# CSS Child Combinator (>) not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-table

For a website I am creating I need to have nested HTML tables. I have styling for the first outside table row (header) that I don't want to be applied for the first rows of the inside tables so I tried using the child combinator like so:

```
 table.outside > tr:first-child {
      # Outside table header row styles
 }
```

However, the style do not get applied to the header row of the outside table but when I remove the child combinator it works.
Here is my HTML:

```
 <table class="outside">
      <tr><!-- This should be styled -->
           <th>Column 1</th>
           <th>Column 2</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
           <td>
                <table>
                     <tr><!-- Table Data --></tr><!-- This should not be styled -->
                     <tr><!-- Table Data --></tr>
                </table>
           </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- Etc. -->
 </table>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Browsers will usually add a `<tbody>` tag if you don't.  Try `table.outside > tbody > tr:first-child`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this selector `table.outside > tbody > tr:first-child`but if you share your code, my help would be better.

Comment: Code shared, sorry about that

Comment: Confirmed: http://jsfiddle.net/QnzkG/5/